# Overview of version control in emacs

Tags: git, emacs, version-control

I just found out that emacs integrates support for version control (via the same problem as, and answer from, [Emacs and symbolic links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15390178/emacs-and-symbolic-links)).  I tried to find an overview of what emacs VC includes, but everything I find is details and technical (e.g. [emacs man for VC](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Version-Control.html)).

**Does anyone know of a quick introduction / overview of emacs VC?**
I.e. Why use it, instead of (e.g.) git directly?  What basic features does it have?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark The entire point of my question is to avoid '*extensive*'.  I do appreciate your point---which I considered---but I decided to still post the question because I thought such a link would be helpful to lots of people on SO, and in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why use it, instead of (e.g.) git directly?

For the same reason one uses other integrated tools and GUIs: less typing, faster turnaround.

> What basic features does it have?

CLI cycle:

1. edit the file
2. switch to shell, run `git commit file`
3. edit the commit message in the new editor; oops - need to look at the original file ...

Emacs cycle:

1. edit the file
2. <kbd>C-x v v</kbd> - new buffer appears for the commit message, you can edit it while viewing the changes you made in a *diff* buffer (<kbd>C-x v =</kbd>); <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> when done and you can resume editing right away.

Or select files in the *vc-dir* buffer (<kbd>C-x v d</kbd>) and operate on them: diff, commit, pull &c.

Just start using Emacs/VC and ask specific questions.

PS. See also Emacs Wiki:

1. [Version Control](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/VersionControl)
2. [Category Version Control](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryVersionControl)

Comment: For git specifically, there's also [magit](http://magit.github.io/magit/), a more visual approach that's tightly coupled to git and supports all of its advanced features.

Answer (score 1):

Here's brief introduction: http://david.rothlis.net/emacs/basic_c.html#vc

If you're using git, you really should be using `magit`, a third-party plugin.
However even with `magit`, I still use `vc`'s `vc-print-log` and, in particular, `vc-annotate`. For an introduction to the latter see http://david.rothlis.net/emacs/basic_c.html#annotate